# How to get the XML structure of the expected input message for an Web Service?

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl

Part of the WSDL contains:

```
- <wsdl:message name="MyObj_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="part" element="q3:UpdateMyObj" xmlns:q3="http://COMPANY.SERVER.Integration.Schemas.UpdatePlacement" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
```

EDIT: Here it goes a complete one. Can't figure out, unless I put the link on SoapUI. How does SoapUI do the magic?

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:i0="http://nservicebus.com" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="ModifyMyObjectServiceV2" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IWcfServiceOf_ModifyMyObjectRequestV2_ErrorCodes_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:import namespace="http://nservicebus.com" location="http://localhost:8080/services/V2/modifymyobjectservice?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWcfServiceOf_ModifyMyObjectRequestV2_ErrorCodes" type="i0:IWcfServiceOf_ModifyObjectRequestV2_ErrorCodes">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IWcfServiceOf_ModifyMyObjectRequestV2_ErrorCodes_policy"/>
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Process">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://nservicebus.com/IWcfServiceOf_ModifyMyObjectRequestV2_ErrorCodes/Process" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ModifyMyObjectServiceV2">
<wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IWcfServiceOf_ModifyMyObjectRequestV2_ErrorCodes" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IWcfServiceOf_ModifyMyObjectRequestV2_ErrorCodes">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/services/V2/modifymyobjectservice"/>
<wsa10:EndpointReference>
<wsa10:Address>
http://localhost:8080/services/V2/modifymyobjectservice
</wsa10:Address>
</wsa10:EndpointReference>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The end.

Comment: Is there an import of an xsd? Maybe that xsd provides the definition of the `UpdateMyObj` element.

Comment: That's meant to be defined in the `wsdl:types` element.

Comment: Use SOAP UI to read the WSDL and create a mock message.